# Selenium PhantomJS driver failed to instantiate

Tags: java, unix, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to instantiate new PhantomJS driver on a server and I get below error when it encounters below java line

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);         
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,path);
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    caps.setCapability("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());
    final List<String> argsList = new LinkedList<>();
    argsList.add("--web-security=false");
    argsList.add("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
    argsList.add("--ssl-protocol=ANY");
    argsList.add("--load-images=yes");
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, argsList.toArray(new String[argsList.size()]));
    caps.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
    LOGGER.info("3 About to Initianiate Browser Now .....");

    final LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
    System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    caps.setCapability("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());
    final List<String> argsList = new LinkedList<>();
    argsList.add("--web-security=false");
    argsList.add("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
    argsList.add("--ssl-protocol=ANY");
    argsList.add("--load-images=yes");
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, argsList.toArray(new String[argsList.size()]));
    caps.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
    LOGGER.info("3 About to Initianiate Browser Now .....");

    final LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);

// ERROR is thrown when it tries to execute below code line 
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);


org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: 
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are 
invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b'
System info: host: 'vsa1119899.server', ip: '10.69.168.57', 
os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.0.101-0.47.71-xen'
java.version: '1.7.0_99' 
Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
```

I run the same code in Windows, Ubuntu it works (I am assigning driver executables based on Platfom i.e., path). When I try to deploy this war on server I get above mentioned error. Can someone tell me why this isn't working on Server.

Any pointers highly appreciated

Comment: What version of PhantomJS are you using?  There were some Selenium changes around that recently I think.  I would avoid 2.53 and use 2.52.2  of Selenium until you figure it out.  Also, I currently use Phantom 2.1.1 ... dont know if your doing the same?

Comment: @djangofan I am using PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Used PhantomJS website which explains building executables from source code http://phantomjs.org/build.html). Created executable on Ubuntu system and referencing the same on Server. Selenium version 2.53.0

Comment: Can you simplify your example to use default capabilities, and if you do, do you get the same result?